# C++ template function overload resolution bug

Tags: c++, templates

```
namespace Random
{
    std::mt19937 engine_{ std::random_device{}() };

    template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
    auto get(T from, T to)
    {
        return std::uniform_int_distribution<T>{from, to}(engine_);
    }

    template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, float>::value>>
    auto get(T from, T to)
    {
    return std::uniform_real_distribution<T>{from, to}(engine_);
    }

}
int main()
{
    std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::boolalpha);
    std::cout << Random::get<float>(1.0f, 2.5f);//COMPILE TIME ERROR
    std::cin.get();
}
```

compiler output: 
18:4: error: redefinition of 'template T Random::get(T, T)'
12:4: note: 'template T Random::get(T, T)' previously declared here
 In function 'int main()':
28:44: error: no matching function for call to 'get(float, float)'
28:44: note: candidate is:
12:4: note: template T Random::get(T, T)
12:4: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

This work fine:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

namespace Random
{
    std::mt19937 engine_{ std::random_device{}() };

    template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
    auto get(T from, T to)
    {
        return std::uniform_int_distribution<T>{from, to}(engine_);
    }

    template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, float>::value>>
    T get(T from, T to)
    {
    return std::uniform_real_distribution<T>{from, to}(engine_);
    }

}
int main()
{
    std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::boolalpha);
    std::cout << Random::get<float>(1.0f, 2.5f);//GOOD
    std::cin.get();
}
```

and this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

namespace Random
{
    std::mt19937 engine_{ std::random_device{}() };

    template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
    auto get(T from, T to)
    {
        return std::uniform_int_distribution<T>{from, to}(engine_);
    }

    template<class T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, float>::value, T>
    get(T from, T to)
    {
        return std::uniform_real_distribution<T>{from, to}(engine_);
    }

}
int main()
{
    std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::boolalpha);
    std::cout << Random::get<float>(1.0f, 2.5f);//GOOD
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Why compilers can't resolve this resolution in first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default argument is not part of the signature, so you compare

```
template <typename T, typename>
auto get(T, T) { /* implementation1 */ }
```

vs

```
template <typename T, typename>
auto get(T, T) { /* implementation2 */ }
```

which is seen as same signature (even if the deduced return type would differ)

In your working examples, you have different signatures (even if auto would be deduced to T)

```
template <typename T, typename>
auto get(T, T) { /* implementation1 */ }
```

vs

```
template<class T, typename>
T get(T, T) { /* implementation2 */ }
```

or

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, float>::value, T>
get(T, T) { /* implementation2 */ }
```

and the call is not ambiguous thanks to SFINAE.

An other way to allow `auto` return type and use SFINAE would be

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>* = nullptr>
auto get(T from, T to)
{
    return std::uniform_int_distribution<T>{from, to}(engine_);
}

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, float>::value>* = nullptr>
auto get(T from, T to)
{
    return std::uniform_real_distribution<T>{from, to}(engine_);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's strange. C++ is full of crutchs as i see = (( going deeper into C ++ I find more minuses in it. THX FOR ANSWER