# c++ template instantiation works with int, long, etc. but not float, double, etc

Tags: c++, templates, primitive-types

I'm working on a little C++ project, for which I created a nice and handy `std::ostream` wrapper called `Logger`.

Inside the class I defined a templated operator:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T> = 0>
friend Logger& operator<<(Logger& logger, const T& logMessage) {
    return logger << std::to_string(logMessage); // there is also an operator overload which takes a std::string& as argument.
}
```

When the template is instanciated with an integral type, like `int` or `long`, the template works like a charm.
So the statement

```
someLoggerInstance << 123 << 456ULL << "\n";
```

compiles just fine.

However if I change the statement to

```
someLoggerInstance << 12.3 << "\n";
```

the compiler shouts at me that the template could not be instantiated.

The error message from the compiler:

```
Candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = double]: a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'typename std::enable_if_t::value, double>' (aka 'double')
```

Where is the problem?

I tried to replace `std::is_arithmetic<T>` with `std::is_integral<T>` and add a second templated function using `std::is_floating_point<T>`, but this does not change anything, the integral template is instantiated, but the floating point template is not, leading to the same error message as above.

If I create an additional overload for the type `double`

```
friend Logger& operator<<(Logger& logger, const double& logMessage) {
    return logger << std::to_string(logMessage);
}
```

the problem gets even worse, since then the complier, trying to pass the `"\n"` at the end, annoys me with the following messages:

```
Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const unsigned char [1]' to 'const double' for 2nd argument
```

and

```
Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const unsigned char [1]' to 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string, allocator >') for 2nd argument
```

Any help or advise would be nice!
Thank you!

---

**Edit**

Thanks for the quick help.

Now changed the template like this:

```
template<typename T, typename TEnable = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, char>::value, T>>
friend Logger& operator<<(Logger& logger, const T& logMessage);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update template to use type template parameter:

```
template
<
    typename T
,   typename TEnabled = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>
>
friend Logger & operator <<(Logger & logger, const T & logMessage) {
    return logger << std::to_string(logMessage);
}
```

Comment: Better to use `std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>* = nullptr`, that allow the disable_if.

Comment: @Jarod42 What would be the difference between *disable_if* and `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>`?

Comment: @Jarod42: Although it works (and has always worked), using `void*` types as non-type template parameters is currently prohibited (although probably it will be allowed eventually. See [EWG 175](https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#175)). I recommend `int` like StoryTeller's answer.

Comment: @songyuanyao: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41175742/2684539 for explanation of what I meant (it is the form `typename = std::enable_if_t<cond>` which might be problematic).

Comment: @Jarod42 It actually may or may not be desirable depending on whether there supposed to be more template operators << in the same namespace or not. I prefer to utilize type template parameter when possible.

Answer (score 3):

When `T` is a double, this thing `std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>` resolves to a `double` as well.

But non-type template parameters are explicitly disallowed to be floating point types. The correct minimal example for your problem is this:

```
template<double d> // this is ill-formed
void foo() {}
```

The rationale is that templates are specialized according to the exact value of the non-type argument. Which is an issue for types to which comparing for direct equality is problematic.

Just have `std::enable_if_t` resolve to a valid type, such as a pointer or an `int` that you initialize with 0.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your first problem an alternative SFINAE is to use `std::enable_if_t` to allow substitution failure for the return type...

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, Logger&>
friend operator<<(Logger& logger, const T& logMessage)
{
    return logger << std::to_string(logMessage);
}
```

Your second problem is because `std::is_arithmetic<char>::value` is `true` so you need to disqualify that case.